# how to stop gradient from switching color mode?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I set my document in CMYK. But Gradient always acts at it's own sweet will.
Whenever i try to apply it on other vector graphics it goes automatically to grayscale. Then every time manually i have to set it back to CMYK.
I dont want gradient to switch on ny other color mode.
Is it possible inside illustrator? 
[image]

Comment: Hi. Although the dialog you show has "grayscale" checked, the gradient stop is shown as 100% K which is a CMYK colour.  Not sure what problem you are trying to solve but I can't see anything wrong here. If you want another mix of CMYK colours intead of K only, then just choose one from the swatches.

Comment: suppose i have two vector graphics on my art board. one is created by me and another one is downloaded. so when i apply gradient on my design the color is CMYK. but if i try to apply gradient on the downloaded one it switched to gray-scale. and i have to change it Every-time from gray-scale to CMYK. i want it to stop. i want gradient to stay in CMYK mode always... is it possible? i even dnt understand why it shifts... its weird.

Answer (score 3):

**Appearance Panel Menu** --- be certain `New Art Has Basic Appearance` is **not** checked.

Answer (score 0):

Check the attributes tab and open the layers if maybe set with   Transparency layer with an active effect.